# Is there a technical term for when verbs in a sentence appear as if they have been swapped around?

Tags: ambiguity, poetry, literary-techniques

Is there a technical term for when verbs in a sentence appear as if they have been swapped around as in the example here?

> 'her fingers creased in gold [and] her body ringed in folds'

In this line, the poet appears to have swapped transitive verbs so that a hall of mirrors is created; the *gold* refers to the *rings*, the *creases* to the *folds*, the *rings* to the *fingers*, and the *creases* to the *body*.

I know what the poet is doing, but I have searched online for the technical term for swapping transitive verbs from their expected contexts and am unable to find any.

Comment: Deliberately misusing words is a form of [catachresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catachresis), but I don't think that captures the idea of swapping *ringed* and *creased* from their more natural contexts.

Answer (score 1):

You can take either "metaphor" or "transposition" as being accurate, but I would go ahead and invent the term "transpositional metaphor" to do the whole job here.